# how to let ffplay process whats happening?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

my ffplay is trying to hard to process something. I sped up my voice in real-time with ffmpeg and I am using ffplay. ffplay is trying to process my voice fast but isn't able to because it cant go past time. someone told me to use -re before -i but that doesnt work. is there a way to get ffplay to process something slower?

i tried speeding up my voice.

when I pause ffplay and talk then resume it, it works perfect. but when I just let it do it in real-time, the audio starts cutting in and out. I want to be able to not have to pause it to talk fast.

i am using ffplay pipe:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note: this needs no further detail or clarity. Just because you don't understand a question does not make it unclear. It's perfectly clear… it would just break the laws of physics.

Comment: Lol, I had to read this a few times before I realized what you did Tetsujin. Yea, laws of reality can be a pain sometimes, right?

Comment: I'm saying I wanna delay my voice and then speed up my delayed voice.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but Einstein won't let you.

The only way it could constantly play back faster than you are speaking is if it eventually started speaking **before you do.**

This tends to upset the delicate balance of the Universe… possibly fatally;)

One thing you could process real-time would be pitch or formant-shifting. This would work at real-time speed, but sound higher [which is part of the effect of speeding it up, pitch & formants are shifted upwards.]

Comment: exactly. i was saying if i could delay it and then speed up the delay? wouldn't that work? i dont want pitch. i want tempo.

Comment: You cannot run this real-time. If you ran a 30s buffer & playback was double-speed, you'd have to re-buffer after 45 seconds. You could extend the buffer of course until you run out of RAM, but imagine you could buffer 30 minutes - playback wouldn't start for 30 minutes & you'd still be out of buffer in another 15.